# Perl: Programmatically drop PostgreSQL table index then re-create after COPY using DBD::Pg

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi, dbd-pg

I'm copying several tables (~1.5M records) from one data source to another, but it is taking a long time.  I'm looking to speed up my use of DBD::Pg.

I'm currently using pg_getcopydata/pg_putcopydata, but I suppose that the indexes on the destination tables are slowing the process down.

I found that I can find some information on table's indexes using `$dbh->statistics_info`, but I'm curious if anyone has a programmatic way to dynamically drop/recreate indexes based on this information.

Answer (score 1):

The programmatic way, I guess, is to submit the appropriate `CREATE INDEX` SQL statements via DBI that you would enter into `psql`.

Sometimes when copying a large table it's better to do it in this order:

- create table with out indexes
- copy data
- add indexes

Comment: If you have archiving turned off and you have no indexes on the table, you can make it *a lot* faster by doing the copy in the same database transaction which created or truncated the table.  It is best to run `VACUUM FREEZE ANALYZE` on a table into which you have just loaded a lot of rows -- it will make access faster, especially on the first access after the commit, and it will prevent a mass update at some unpredictable future date to freeze the transaction IDs in the tuples to prevent transaction ID wraparound.

Comment: By programmatic I meant dynamic, sorry.  There are many tables and the account writing does not have permission to create tables, but it does have the ability to alter the constraints.